# CSS3 rounded corners in chrome render inconsistently

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rounded-corners

[image]
[image]

When the page loads the div with the rounded corners shows like the first image. If I go into the developer tools, inspect the element then toggle the bg color off then on it then looks like the second image.

Basically any kind of in chrome alteration of that element, then undoing to how it was removes the rendering issue.

I know it's a little vague and having the code would help but it is so obscure - rounded corners work elsewhere.

It's a div with this css:

```
background-color: rgb(0, 172, 237);  
border-bottom-left-radius: 16px;  
border-bottom-right-radius: 16px;  
border-top-left-radius: 16px;  
border-top-right-radius: 16px;  
box-sizing: border-box;  
color: rgb(80, 88, 92);  
cursor: default;  
display: block;  
float: left;  
font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;  
font-size: 16px;  
height: 613px;  
line-height: 16px;  
margin-bottom: 0px;  
margin-left: 0px;  
margin-right: 0px;  
margin-top: 0px;  
padding-bottom: 0px;  
padding-left: 0px;  
padding-right: 0px;  
padding-top: 0px;  
width: 920px;
```

Comment: also sometimes the blue area renders with square corners. If you then again change a css value in the developer tools then change back it suddenly renders fine.

Comment: Works perfectly in other browsers.

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Please post a *complete* code example, which in this case includes your HTML and all relevant CSS.

Comment: This has happened to me with other effects on chrome, where opening inspector tools, or even moving the window around a little bit would fix the issue. However, I have never seen it to happen with border radius. Once I have read that it can be a GPU acceleration issue. Try to add: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to disable the acceleration and see if you still have the same problem. Also, please post your code in jsfiddle or something, so we can see maybe its not a chrome issue at all.

Comment: I just tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` and it definitely made some improvement. Going to look into this further and other rendering settings.